# Ifelse condition without creating NA's

Tags: r, if-statement

I have a data.frame with Start times and Stop times. If `Start` > 1 AND `Stop` < 5, I want to write a name in a new column. I have 15 different names in total with different conditions I want to execute manually after one an other. For this, it is crucial, that no NAs are getting created.

**What can I put instead of `NA`, so it skips the rows which don't fulfill the condition?**

What I have so far:

```
data.frame$names <- ifelse(
    (data.frame$Start >=1) & (data.frame$Stop<=5),
    print('Name'), 
    NA)
```

I tried using `if` like this, but nothing happened:

```
if (data.frame$Start => 1 && data.frame$Stop <=5) {
    data.frame$names = print ('Name')
}
```

I would like to have a new column, that returns "name" when`Start`=>1 AND `Stop`<=5, and returns "name2" to `Start`>=5 AND `Stop` <= 10. My expected solution looks like this:

```
        Start Stop Names
    1      1    2  name
    2      2    3  name
    3      3    4  name
    4      4    5  name
    5      5    6 name2
    6      6    7 name2
    7      7    8 name2
    8      8    9 name2
    9      9   10 name2
    10    10   11
```

Here is a reproducible example dataset:

```
Start<- c(1:10)
Stop<- c(2:11)
df=data.frame(Start,Stop)
df
       Start Stop
    1      1    2
    2      2    3
    3      3    4
    4      4    5
    5      5    6
    6      6    7
    7      7    8
    8      8    9
    9      9   10
    10    10   11
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I just added a reproducible example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an option using `case_when` -

```
library(dplyr)

df <- df %>%
  mutate(Names = case_when(Start >= 1 & Stop <= 5 ~ 'name', 
                           Start >= 5 & Stop <= 10 ~ 'name2', 
                           TRUE ~ ''))
df

#   Start Stop Names
#1      1    2  name
#2      2    3  name
#3      3    4  name
#4      4    5  name
#5      5    6 name2
#6      6    7 name2
#7      7    8 name2
#8      8    9 name2
#9      9   10 name2
#10    10   11
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `''` to instead of `NA`:

```
data.frame$Names <- ifelse(((data.frame$Start >1) & (data.frame$Stop<5)),print('Name'),'')
```

Edit following comments:
the dplyr solution below is elegant and easy to read. In base R, you could also embed two `ifelse` like this:

```
df$Names <- ifelse(((df$Start >=1) & (df$Stop<=5)),print('Name'),
              ifelse(((df$Start >=5) & (df$Stop<=10)),print('Name2'),''))

> df
   Start Stop Names
1      1    2  Name
2      2    3  Name
3      3    4  Name
4      4    5  Name
5      5    6 Name2
6      6    7 Name2
7      7    8 Name2
8      8    9 Name2
9      9   10 Name2
10    10   11
```

Comment: Thank you Mata, 
but when I want to give the next name the old names get overwritten:
data.frame$names <- ifelse (((data.frame$Start >5) & (data.frame$Stop<10)), print('Name2'), '')
So after that the old 'Name's are replaced by ''.

Comment: @Maike That is  most likely not related to `''` or `NA`, which is just what you put in the column. I am not sure I totally get your problem, could you make a reproducible example and what the results should look like? I mean, provide an example of the original data, and an example of the result (it doesn't have to be your real data)? So that I can test the transformation.

Comment: Okay, I see the problem. I just added an example in the question, hope it works. Thank you!!